# implementation of user class in php

Tags: php, class, model-view-controller

I'm fairly new to php oop and I'm starting to get the hang of things. Though I have extended procedural experience, I've only recently started to build my own MVC framework, mainly for learning purposes. I got to the stage where I know how to route url's to controllers and models and render views based on what's requested. What I struggle with is a conceptual thing:

My application has users, which have to log in in order to use it. If you're not logged in, nothing happens. These users are objects and have methods like login(), logout(), auth() etc.

At the same time, I would like to have a "module" in my application where certain users can manage users, like root for example. A page where I can see all users, add new ones, remove existing ones, reset passwords etc. ...

While I know how to build the latter, I'm confused about where the login() and logout() actions should go. Are these part of the UsersController or should I have a separate class for them, despite technically dealing with the same object type?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## MVC and the chess game

This is to help you understand what's the Model, the View and the Controller and how each layer might be used.

Let's suppose that you want to implement a chess game in MVC.

The rules are essential for a chess game. The rules are the Model layer.

You may play with with a wooden board, or using a computer, or using only your mind to represent the state of the game. The representation of the game is the View layer.

Of course, the rules and the representation of the game don't tell how the moves are chosen. There might be humans or some machine playing the game. Different humans and machines usually make different decisions. Those are the controllers. The fingers, pointer devices, keyboards are also controllers. They interact with the Model. All those controllers belong the Controller layer.

Let's suppose that in the Model layer there's a method:

`MoveResponse ChessGame::move(from, to)`

That doesn't mean that there shouldn't be some method:

`void HumanPlayer::move(from, to)`

The human interacts with the game using, for instance, a mouse. There could be something like that:

`MouseGameController::onClick(x, y)`

Using the board representation (from the View), it would convert the click position to the board position (in the model), check if there's some game piece there and notify the View for visual feedback.

If there was some game piece and the player clicks again, `void HumanPlayer::move(from, to)` would be called, that would call `MoveResponse ChessGame::move(from, to)` and the returned `MoveResponse` would be used to update the View. Some method would evaluate the content of the `MoveResponse` and call the appropriate method, for instance, to move a piece with an animation and make some sound.

## Where to put the login and logout

Someone has to login and logout. That's a decision made by the user, therefore it should be in the controller.

Nevertheless, since it's possible to login and logout, there are users models. You need to access users data, change them, know what's the current user, etc. I believe the login/logout functionality should be implemented in the Model, but how that's invoked should be implemented in the Controller.

In the Model it's not important how you proceeded to login or logout, or how those events were triggered: you clicked the "Esc" key, or you clicked a button, or you sent a HTTP message, etc. That's the Controller responsibility. Implement the login and logout without thinking how the user will login or logout, then use something else to call what you implemented when the user wants to login or logout.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the idea controllers are limited to map the actions of a router to a function, but the db connection and other things involved exported to other layers of your framework and just to be called there.

Comment: Are you saying that it would be best to have application wide functionality (db, auth, log, debug etc.) separate and only use mvc for the actual functionality of the app? That would make a lot of sense...

Comment: that depends on the scope you set for yourself to study in your framework. Laravel, for example, has an ORM called Eloquent. You can either one of them on your framework as a dependency (using [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) to manage it) or create your own.